# Gradle clean<customTask> not working

Tags: gradle

I have a custom task to do a Websphere EJBDeploy.  I have defined the inputs and ouputs, and get successful incremental compilation, but I can't get the automatically generated clean task to work properly.

According to docs, for a custom task named "ejbDeploy" with a defined output, a cleanEjbDeploy [task should be automatically generated](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/10/gradle-goodness-automatic-clean-tasks.html).

```
Pattern: clean<TaskName>: Cleans the output files of a task.
```

So here's my custom task:

```
task ejbDeploy(dependsOn: 'jar'){
    srcFile = file(jar.archivePath)
    destDir = new File("build/ejbDeploy")

    inputs.file srcFile
    outputs.dir destDir

    def cp = project.files(
        project.sourceSets.main.output.classesDir,
        project.sourceSets.main.resources,
        project.configurations.runtime
        ).getAsPath()

    doLast{
        destDir.mkdirs()

        exec{
            executable = wasEjbDeploy
            workingDir = destDir
            args = [
                jar.archivePath,
                ".",
                jar.archiveName,
                "-cp",
                cp
            ]
        }   
    }
}
```

Anyone have any ideas as to why the clean rule isn't working?

[Edit]

Here's the full (anonymized) file contents (this has changed since initial question post):

```
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
group = 'com.company'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'name.benjaminAbbitt', name: 'WASEjbDeploy', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'base'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.4.5'
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.16'
    compile files(fileTree(dir: 'lib', includes: ['*.jar']) )
}

task ejbDeploy(type:name.benjaminAbbitt.WASEjbDeploy, dependsOn: 'jar'){
    wasEjbDeployPath = wasEjbDeploy
}
```

Here's the relevant chunk of "$gradle tasks"

```
build - Assembles and tests this project.
buildDependents - Assembles and tests this project and all projects that depend
on it.
buildNeeded - Assembles and tests this project and all projects it depends on.
classes - Assembles the main classes.
clean - Deletes the build directory.
jar - Assembles a jar archive containing the main classes.
testClasses - Assembles the test classes.

Documentation tasks
-------------------
javadoc - Generates Javadoc API documentation for the main source code.

Help tasks
----------
dependencies - Displays the dependencies of project ':project'.
help - Displays a help message
projects - Displays the sub-projects of project ':project'.
properties - Displays the properties of project ':project'.
tasks - Displays the tasks runnable from project ':project' (some of the
displayed tasks may belong to subprojects).

IDE tasks
---------
cleanEclipse - Cleans all Eclipse files.
eclipse - Generates all Eclipse files.

Verification tasks
------------------
check - Runs all checks.
test - Runs the unit tests.

Other tasks
-----------
ejbDeploy

Rules
-----
Pattern: build<ConfigurationName>: Assembles the artifacts of a configuration.
Pattern: upload<ConfigurationName>: Assembles and uploads the artifacts belongin
g to a configuration.
Pattern: clean<TaskName>: Cleans the output files of a task.

To see all tasks and more detail, run with --all.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3.321 secs
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The clean rule is provided by the `base` plugin. Since many other plugins (e.g. `java`) already apply the `base` plugin, you typically don't have to apply the `base` plugin yourself. But in case:

```
apply plugin: "base"
```

Comment: Both 'java' and 'base' are imported into the build.gradle that includes the custom ejbDeploy task.

Comment: Double-check that the plugin is applied to the same project that _declares_ the task. If that's the case, you've found a bug, although it's somewhat hard to believe. Also check whether `gradle tasks` displays the task rule when executed for that project.

Comment: Thanks for helping!  Additional information in the base post now.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I can't get the automatically generated clean task to work properly"? What happens when you call it?

Comment: I just tried it again and for whatever reason it now works successfully.  I must have had an error somewhere in one of the tasks.  Thanks for your help Peter.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser what I noticed is that given a custom task `ejbDeploy` the clean task is generated `cleanEjbDeploy` and is working. Also `gradle ejbDep` works fine and resolves as if I did `gradle ejbDeploy`, but the same doesn't happen when calling `clean<>` via the shorthand: `gradle cleanEjbDep`.

Comment: Maybe it's worth noting that the Android Gradle plugin does not apply / depend on the `base` plugin, hence you usually do not have auto-generated clean tasks in Android projects.